# Algorithm to come up with shortest day to reach a goal

Tags: algorithm, big-o, divide-and-conquer

I am given this problem and not quite sure how to approach it.

I was thinking maybe the best way is to go 1km east then 2km west then 3km easy... and so on until we reach the exit.

We are standing in the middle on a tunnel that goes left-right. At some unknown number of K kilometers from us, is the exit. We do not know whether the exit is located in east or west. Neither do know the distance K to the exit.

We want to walk to the in as few days as possible. Assume we can walk 50 kilometers each day. Give an algorithm that will ensure we reach the exit in `O(K)` days. Argue that your algorithm is correct. Explain your algorithm on an example.

Comment: Are there any details or clues about the tunnel?  Based on what you gave us, I don't see any way out other than brute force walking in one direction until you hit either end.

Comment: Hi, I would like to help you with this problem statement. However, the question is not completely clear.

Can you elaborate?

Comment: O(K) seems hard, an O(K * ln K) seems possible using binary search...well, maybe not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to oscillate between going east and west but instead of increasing the amplitude by one, double it each time.

1. Go west 1 km.
2. Return to home position, and go east 2 km.
3. Return to home, go west 4km.
   ...

This will ensure that you reach the exit in O(K) days. This is because, if K is 2^p, then before reaching the exit, you would have travelled at the most O(2^p) km.

Ex: If K = 2^n + 1, the worst case can be:
1
1 + 2
2 + 4
4 + 8
8 + 16
...
2^(n)  + 2^(n+1)
2^(n+1) + 2^n + 1
(O (9K) ).